# include graphics macOS Catalina

Tags: mac, mactex, includegraphics

Help!
Ever since I upgraded my machine to macOS Catalina, non of my tex files can use `\incdludegrapics`. As far as I know this is the only change done to my system recently.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall my TeX distribution, but that didn't help.

I use Texstudio, and BasicTeX (MacTeX minimal package).

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{pic.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Erro from my log file:

```
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.7         \includegraphics[width=2in]{pic.png}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Any thoughts?

Full log file below:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.10.11)  11 OCT 2019 13:14
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/07/20 v1.3b Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(./document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count88
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchbox=\box27
\nofMPsegments=\count89
\nofMParguments=\count90
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count91
\MPscratchDim=\dimen106
\MPnumerator=\count92
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count93
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.7         \includegraphics[width=2in]{pic.png}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...e \expandafter {\@curr@file 
                                                  }}\expandafter \filename@p...
l.7         \includegraphics[width=2in]{pic.png}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \unquote@name 

l.7         \includegraphics[width=2in]{pic.png}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

l.7         \includegraphics[width=2in]{pic.png}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

l.7         \includegraphics[width=2in]{pic.png}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: File `pic.png' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7         \includegraphics[width=2in]{pic.png}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./document.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1431 strings out of 494060
 20855 string characters out of 6163034
 77505 words of memory out of 5000000
 5144 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 319 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,4n,25p,275b,151s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/a
msfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 11589 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: You might wanbt to mention that you are not really using MacTeX but the smaller Basic TeX (just if it matters). Is it fully up to date?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is the line `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>` in your log. My fully updated TeXLive 2019 says `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>` and some of the items in that error was changed lately and needs that LaTeX version

Comment: Thanks for the remark, updated the question. To answer yours, I just reinstalled the distribution, so yes.

Comment: @daleif How do I update `LaTeX2e`? Isn't it part of the basic Tex distro?
Regardless, I used basic Tex before the update last week.

Comment: Note that MacTeX etc all are snapshots in time, they need updating to get the updates since when they were gathered. There should be a point and click interface, do not remember where (not a mac user). Or command line: `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` (btw: why not install all of MacTeX)

Comment: @daleif this is the second time I've seen someone ask about the Latex2e version recently, w.r.t. <2018-12-01>. Could there be an issue in the TL distribution somehow? (I also get <2018-12-01>, and I just did the `tlmgr update --self --all` sequence yesterday.) (Full MacTeX installation.)

Comment: @dedded you probably need to check whether your mirror is up to date (it takes a little while before the changes propagate to the mirrors, but they should be fully out by now). Did you run run `tlmgr` wit sudo and have you tried today?

Comment: @daleif I have a system-wide install, so I do have to run with sudo. (I don't see why that would matter.) I will try updating again tonight.

Comment: @dedded I do not remember what happens on a Mac if you run tlmgr without sudo (the debian TeXLive makes tlmgr only run locally not globally so there is a difference in what it can do), it can probably not redo the format. Running it with sudo should rebuild the format as the updates tells it to.

Comment: @daleif Following your suggestions I installed also the full distro to see what happens. I can switch between them by configuring a distro via the tex live utility. I updated both today. 
The basic distro downs work while the full one does. Can I conclude that at least in the mirror I'm using there's an issue with the basic distro in OS Catalina? I use http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet

Comment: @daleif Indeed, in the full installation I get `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>` in the log file

Comment: @dedded try `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` @YairM you might want to try it on the BasicTeX as well. That is a forced rebuild of the formats.

Comment: @YairM that mirror seems to be up to date. Try the manual format rebuild in my comment above

Comment: @dedded this indeed resolved the issue. Since I don't understand exactly what happened or what was the solution, could you give me some details so I'd learn? Additionally, if you post this as a solution, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @YairM did it work on basictex? Then perhaps we need to send that on to the developers that a format rebuild was not triggered after updating

Comment: @daleif it did, yet I'm not sure what exactly should I send, or to whom.

Comment: I can pass it on to the texlive mailing list

Comment: Thanks, I believe this would be helpful for others too.

Comment: @daleif I did another tlmgr update, and then the fmtutil-sys command, and I now see <2019-10-01>.  As for what tlmgr w/o sudo does on a Mac, it's just what you would do if you had Texlive installed in one user's home area instead of system-wide. I have it installed system-wide and so need to use sudo.